# Errors while adding binary to App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I was trying to implement in-app purchase. I am using ios 5.0 beta and xcode 4.2. Now I am remaining with only error. Also when I add my binary to iTunes Connect through Application Loader I get this error:

[image: third error]

Please help me with it!

Comment: i have distribution certificate in my keychain and profile in my xcode but still its giving error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

I just re-read your question, and it's probably my fault for not paying more attention the first time, but you can probably ignore my previous answer..

What I believe is the problem is that you're using the 5.0 beta SDK to write and submit your app. This can't be done. Apple will not accept apps written with beta software.

You must compile and submit your app with the 4.3 SDK.

---

A lot of those errors can't be made any more clear than they already are...

Firstly, your app needs an armv6 binary, so make sure you're not building only the current active architecture.

You need to provide an icon that is 57 x 57 in size and specify it in the info plist with the CFBundleIconFile key.

Your code signing is invalid. Ensure you are using the correct distribution certificate and that you have a valid provisioning profile.

Comment: but my valid architecture are armv6, 7, 7f and 7k and i have added the icon file in plist but don't know what is CFBundleIconFIle key?

Comment: i followed the guide in ios developer portal to work with distribution profile

Comment: ok.. what if i change the deployment target to ios 4.0, then would it run? and what should i do in edit schemes as my target is showing in red color.

Comment: No, the deployment target only specifies the lowest version of iOS your app will support. You need to not use the 5.0 SDK. That means not using Xcode 4.2. If you don't have it, you need to download and install Xcode 4.1 which includes the iOS 4.3 SDK. You can only submit apps using that IDE and SDK. You should not be using beta SDKs to submit apps.

Comment: i am note done 100% with my app so should i need to upload binary through application loader or it would be just fine to add my app and product to tune?

Comment: i am following this link http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/.

Comment: Why are you submitting your app if it is not finished?

Comment: but it will not be reviewed i guess! by apple. I am confused where to put its status developers rejected. I am doing only for sake of running my application, its not fetching product id's from server. that is my basic problem.

Comment: The steps in that tutorial you linked are as clear as they can get. If you're unable to follow them, I don't what I can do to help. The problem still stands and you have not addressed the fact that you're still using a Beta SDK. Do not use a Beta SDK to submit apps. That is the last I will say on this.

Comment: @ketanrajput let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2759/discussion-between-jasarien-and-ketan-rajput)

Answer (score 4):

At the moment it is not possible to submit binaries that were created with Xcode4.2 and link against iOS5. This restriction will be lifter when iOS5 and Xcode4.2 come out of beta. At the moment you will need to use Xcode 4.1 to submit a binary to Apple (which won't work if you need iOS5 features or ARC).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it necessary to make a build of project through app store distribution provisioning profile?

When you want to test you iPhone App with In-App Purchase you will need a development provisioning profile setup with your app's id.

To do this:

- Go to iOS Provisioning Portal ( http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action )
- Create a new App ID e.g. com.test.my_app
- Go to Provisioning and Create a new iOS Development Provisioning Profile with the App ID from before
- Go to XCode set your app up with the correct App ID and new Provisioning Profile you just made.

Comment: what to do with code signing identity? should i give reference of development provisioning profile for debug or for release? while testing.

Comment: While testing I normally debug using my development provisioning profile. I it answers your question